# Jquery, delete dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to delete some div block which contains a bunch of content, I have a div bloc inside it I can add some content dynamically using a button also existing withing the same div, without adding content deleting the block is working fine, however when I add some content inside this bloc its not totally deleted, the dynamically added content is not deleted.

Here's my code :

```
<div class="collection form_lignefacturefournisseur" >

    <div class="portlet box green">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Produit de Bon de Livraison N°<span id="spanidbl{{ loop.index }}">{{ loop.index }}</span></div>
            <div class="tools">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
                <a href="" class="remove"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-1 control-label">N° BL</label>
                 <div class="col-md-2">
                    {{form_widget(ligneffm.idbl,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                     <span class="help-block">{{form_widget(ligneffm.idbl)}}</span>     
                 </div>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-scrollable table-striped table-hover table-bordered table_form_lignefacturefournisseur{{ loop.index }}" id="lignedevistable{{ loop.index }}" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 188px;">Produit</th>
                    <th>Quntité</th>
                    <th>Prix HT</th>
                    <th>Sous Total HT</th>
                    <th>Action</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            {% for ligneff in ligneffm.ligneff %}
                <tr class="ligneproduit{{loop.index}}">
                    <td>{{ form_widget(ligneff.idarticle,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}</td>
                    <td style="display:none;">{{ form_widget(ligneff.libelleligneff,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form_widget(ligneff.qtLignefacturefournisseur) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ form_widget(ligneff.prixLignefacturefournisseur) }}</td>
                    <td style="display:none;">{{ form_widget(ligneff.listeprixarticle) }}</td>
                    <td class="inputdesible">{{ form_widget(ligneff.totalLignefacturefournisseur) }}</td>
                    <td> <a class="remove btn red" title="Remove" idx="{{loop.index}}"><i class="fa fa-eraser"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}

                <tr id="lignefacturefournisseurtr" style="display:none" >   
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td> 
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    <input id="form_lignefacturefournisseur_btn__namear__"  class="form_lignefacturefournisseur_btn btn green fa fa-plus" type="button" value="Ajouter" /><i style="display:none" id="countTiwg">{{loop.length}}</i>
        </div>
```

The deleted part of the code is :

```
<div class="portlet box green">
    <div class="portlet-title">
        <div class="caption"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Produit de Bon de Livraison N°<span id="spanidbl{{ loop.index }}">{{ loop.index }}</span></div>
        <div class="tools">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"></a>
            <a href="" class="remove"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the other part that contains the added content is not deleted

The jQuery code is as following:

```
$('.tools a.remove').live('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.portlet-body').remove();
        $(this).closest('div [class*="form_lignefacturefournisseur"]').remove();
        blCount--;
    });
```

Note : Ive tried several methods of invocking the click event, the same thing/result.

Any idea , thanks in advance!

Comment: jQuery's `live` has been deprecated and removed from jQuery ?

Comment: Use `$().on('click' function() {}};`

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're trying to remove `.portlet-body` and it is not there in the removed HTML sample.  Which is the *added content*..? What exactly are you trying to do..?

Comment: As mentioned by adeneo, this method is deprecated AND you should use delegated events if you need to set an event on an element which is not yet in the page on page load.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me, "adebeo" and "SearchForKnowledge", I used on instead of live, but Ive the same result,
"T J" , if you see the part after this line {% for ligneff in ligneffm.ligneff %} , using a button I add some rows inside a table located inside the "portlet-body", when I add rows dynamically , the rows of the table are not deleted, hopefully I was clear!

Comment: add a `console.log` and see if you get any response on your clicks.

Comment: yes I got response from console.log

Comment: @krachleur that means that something is wrong with your selectors.

Comment: You need on extra `.parent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for trying to help me, what I found, is that the button I was working on, has some work in the background, I'm using a template that help me with functionnalities, what Ive done is that I let it and created another button, work with it :

```
$(".supprimer_bl").live("click", function() {
            var idBl = $(this).parent().parent().parent().get(0);
            console.log('the class of the element is : ', idBl);
            idBl.remove();
          //  $('.'+classCont).remove();
          //  $(this).closest('div [class*="form_lignefacturefournisseur"]').contents().remove();
            blCount--;
        });
```